# Cannot read property 'roles' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, roles

I want my bot to send a private message to the user that joins my server.

To do this I used:

```
 client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
   const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'benvenuto');
  channel.send(`Date il benvenuto a ${member}!`);
  member.send('test');
});
```

As soon as a user joins the server, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null
    at Client.client.on.message (C:\Users\Kikkiu\Desktop\BotTuttofare\index.js:9:19)
    [...]
```

The error brings me to this part of the code:

```
if(message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Admin") || message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Mod")) {
  if(!message.author.bot) {

  if(message.content == '.del50')
  message.channel.bulkDelete(50)

  if(message.content == '.del100')
  message.channel.bulkDelete(100)

  if(message.content == '.del1')
  message.channel.bulkDelete(2)

  if(message.content == '.del10')
  message.channel.bulkDelete(10)

  if(message.content == '.del2')
  message.channel.bulkDelete(3)
}}
```

If I remove the part that sends the private message I don't get this error. What could it be?

Comment: It means that `message.member` is `null` something is happening before this part in the code.

Comment: Actually there isn't much happening before. The fact is that when I use the command `.del100` (or when I delete the part that sends the message) it works, I don't get this error. I used `if(message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Admin") || message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Mod")) {` in another bot too and it works just fine.

Comment: Message.member is only available if the message comes from a guild.  Is it possible the bot is receiving a direct message?

Regardless, you need to validate member and make sure it isn't null before you act on it.

Comment: No, the bot isn't receiving any direct messages.To check that member isn't null I used `client.on('message', message => {
  if(message.member) {
    console.log('test')
  }}`
Member isn't null. I used `if(message.member.roles) {` too, same result. But, as soon as a user joins the server, it gives the error above. (I forgot to mention that the bot successfully sends the private message to the user, but crashes with the error above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can find roles on members like this.
You use the `.find()` on guilds (`member.guild.roles.find(r => r.name == "Admin")`)

If you want to check if they got the corect role something like this should work:

```
let adminRole = message.guild.roles.get("ADMIN_ROLE_ID") //same with mod role
if (message.member.roles.has(adminRole.id)) {
//If they have admin & mod role they can do this
} else {
//If they do not have the one of the roles, this happens. Either just do return; or do //something like dm them that they don't have roles/permissions
}
```

But I do suggest you make a seperate commad for this where you use args or something to define how much you want to bulk in a channel, this is just confusing.